# Get data into tabular format on printing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-files

I have a program which takes attendee’s names and contact details and writes them to a text file. In all, there are 20 rows and 5 columns which are used in my form so that when the user clicks on the ‘Save’ button, these details are written to a text file.

The code I am using works fine, and is shown below. Please note that this code is truncated to the first attendee only.

```html
Dim AttendeeData = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Attendee Information\" & TextBox1.Text))

        Dim FileNameTXT As String = Path.Combine(AttendeeData.FullName, "Attendee Data" + ".TXT")
        Dim FileTXT As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FileNameTXT)

        ‘Write the Attendee details to the text file

        ‘Attendee Number 1
   
        FileTXT.Write(Form1.TextBox2.Text)   ‘Attendee’s Name               
        FileTXT.WriteLine("")
        
        FileTXT.Write(Form1.TextBox3.Text)   ‘Attendee's Nationality               
        FileTXT.WriteLine("")
        
        FileTXT.Write(Form1.TextBox4.Text)   ‘Attendee's Position              
        FileTXT.WriteLine("")
        
        FileTXT.Write(Form1.TextBox5.Text)   ‘Attendee's Email              
        FileTXT.WriteLine("")
      
        FileTXT.Write(Form1.TextBox6.Text)   ‘Attendee's telephone No.              
        FileTXT.WriteLine("")

        ‘Attendee Number 2 ... to Attendee Number 20

        'The below line of code closes the writer
        FileTXT.Close()
```

I decided to use this method because at some point, the text file has to be read from the text file, back into the textboxes on my form.

My problem is that when it comes to reporting, printing out these details in the above format would be cumbersome, using up sheets of paper to make the report unnecessarily plentiful. So I reckoned that displaying these data in a tabular format would be much more tidy and professional.

Please how can I achieve this? I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express. Thank you in advance.

The code I am currently using in printing is shown below:

```html
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim AttendeeData = New DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Attendee Information\" & TextBox1.Text))

        For Each AttendeeDetailsTXT As FileInfo In AttendeeData.GetFiles("*.TXT",          SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
            For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(AttendeeDetailsTXT.FullName)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then RichTextBox1.AppendText(line & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            Next
        Next
' Send data to printing script

End Sub
```

Comment: fileTXT.Write(vbTab) as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about recording the attendee's information in a structured format such as XML?

Writing the data to XML in code is quite simple - here is a good article on the subject: http://vb.net-informations.com/xml/create-xml-vb.net.htm

Reading the data back into your application will also be much simpler as you no longer have to rely on the lines in your unstructured input file being in a particular order which could cause issues with data being out of sync if, for example, a line is missing.

Displaying the data is slightly more tricky as you would have to use something like an XSLT to display your data in a tabular form but there are plenty of resources online which could get you started with this such as the W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp